# How to find $\sqrt[3]{0.5964}$ using logarithms?

Tags: logarithms, radicals

\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{0.5964} &=   \left(0.5964\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
\log \sqrt[3]{0.5964} &=  \frac{1}{3} \log 0.5964\\
 &=  \frac{1}{3} \cdot\overline{1}.7755\\
 &=  \frac{1}{3}\cdot\left(\overline{3} +2.7755\right)\\
 &=  \overline{1}.9252
                                               \end{align*}

Can anyone explain what happened in line 4

Many Thanks

Comment: Nobody can explain this, because nobody can read it.

Comment: Does ${\overline{1}}$ and ${\overline{3}}$ mean to subtract that digit?

Comment: no it means bar 1 and 3 or negative 1 & 3

Comment: So it means to subtract that digit.

Comment: Please take a look at [our tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can type your posts properly here.

Comment: that means -1.7755 and -3 :)

Comment: sure :) i will take a look

Comment: $\left(0.5964\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=  \frac{1}{3} \log 0.5964$, you say? Sure about this?

Comment: Finally, you gets $\sqrt[3]{0.5964}=10^{-1+0.9252}=10^{0.9252} \times 10^{-1} \approx 8.42 \times 10^{-1} = 0.842$

Comment: What is this notation?! Are you a time traveler?

Comment: The notation is standard [bar notation](https://www.google.com/search?q=logarithms+%22bar+notation%22) that is used with numerical logarithm calculations. The bar is intended to be a negative sign that applies only to the characteristic, not the mantissa, and its placement over the characteristic is intended to be suggestive of this meaning. Also, it occurs to me that user360471 might not have been aware that this notation would be unfamiliar to so many math adepts, being a relative beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that $$\overline{1}.7755=-1+0.7755=-3+2.7755$$ Then divide by $3$ to get $$-1+0.9252=\overline{1}.9252$$ This is a way of keeping a positive mantissa.

Comment: Many Thanks but the question is how 2.7755 come ?

Comment: $-1+0.7755=-3+2.7755$ Then we can divide by $3$

Comment:  Thanks , Ok now i get it

Comment: That's the origin for logarithms, doing multiplication and division by means of addition and subtraction while root by means of division.  It brings back my memories of looking up mathematical tables instead of using calculators.